# Is Spring Batch an overkill

Tags: spring-batch

I need to load a CSV into a database once a week. There is some data massaging required as the CSV file has data for 2 tables. So I will have to process the CSV file a bit, probably convert it into 2 different CSV files and load it into a database.

I already have quartz configured in place. Do you think it would be an overkill to  use spring batch to do the job? I am wondering when should I use it and when should I just do away with quartz bean do the processing itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Batch is perfect for these kinds of jobs because it *reduces* the parts that you have to care about. In this case, all you care about is massaging the data and then inserting into two different tables. You could read the data using the `FileItemReader`. Then use an `ItemProcessor` to change any incoming data and output the correct data, properly massaged. You supply the `itemProcessor` since it's your custom Java logic. Then you can use the `JdbcItemWriter` or simply plug in your own.

**The nicest part about this is that it's** 
**[a]** super commonplace so there's lots and lots and lots of examples (see:  [Spring Batch 2.0 – Part II – Flat File To Database](http://blogs.justenougharchitecture.com/?p=122) or [joshlong/joshlong-examples/spring-batch-starter](https://github.com/joshlong/joshlong-examples/blob/master/spring-batch-starter/batch/src/main/resources/flexible-reader.xml) or the samples in Spring batch itself for inspiration) and 
**[b]** it's mostly declarative. You don't have to worry about the things you don't care about - you're not in the business of figuring out how to correctly parse CSV files, or even how to read files in in a scalable way. You just want to make sure the data is valid and make sure it ends up where it's supposed to end up.

Comment: I agree with this assessment for the most part, but remember that spring-batch is not a panacea.

The down side to Spring Batch (or any framework) is that for some tasks you can spend hours digging through the framework code to figure out why something isn't working.  The only symptom for a lot of issues (minor and major) is that stuff just doesn't work, and the logging is not good at telling you what isn't there.  Maybe someday Spring will add a "read programmers mind" class to their stack.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch adds extra requirements and maintenance pain:

- You need to structure your code in String Batch idiomatic way (implement thier interfaces).
- You need to write some XML or Java configs - one extra DSL to learn.
- You need admin tool to start / stop / monitor execution. Spring Batch Admin is officially deprecated and unmaintained.
- You need to maintain `BATCH_` tables, define index strategy (missing by default), define periodic tables cleanups.
- I've learnt Spring Batch via debug sessions and source code as documentation touches only simple cases (like CSV -> DB).

Comment: Do you have any alternative suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Quartz + service layer. Haven't any experience with: https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch/wiki & http://www.jeasy.org/